# partial class template specialization for a derived class

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I'm trying to write a program that draws user interface elements on an LCD for an embedded Linux system. I have a base class called `Widget` that implements basic functionality like drawing and erasing, and has attributes like x/y location and width/height. I then have derived classes `Label`, `Button`, and `ProgressBar` that add their own attributes (text, focus, and value, respectively).

My problem is that I want to create a template container class called `WidgetArray` that will automatically generate a grid of widgets, and edit their properties en mass. However, if `WidgetArray` contains, for example, a function that takes a vector of strings and assigns each string to the `text` property of a `Label`, if I declare an instance of `WidgetArray` containing `ProgressBar`s (which have no text attribute), the compiler complains. This appears to be a perfect case for template specialization. I was reading the page on template specialization at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) and saw this:

> When we declare specializations for a template class, we must also define all its members, even those exactly equal to the generic template class, because there is no "inheritance" of members from the generic template to the specialization.

Please tell me there is a way around this. The vast majority of the member functions of `WidgetArray` are perfectly valid for all derived classes of `Widget` and it seems incredibly stupid that I have to copy and paste the *entire code* for `WidgetArray` just to add one specialized function for a derived class.

Here's a somewhat simplified version of the code I have:

```
template<class T>
class WidgetArray {
protected:
    std::vector<T> children;
    int columns, x, y;
    int element_w, element_h;
    int x_padding, y_padding; 
public:
    WidgetArray() {
        columns = 1;
        children.resize(1);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    WidgetArray(int x_in, int y_in, int size, int cols) {
        unsigned int counter1=0, counter2=0;
        columns = cols;
        x = x_in;
        y = y_in;
        element_w = 10;
        element_h = 10;
        x_padding = 0;
        y_padding = 0;
        children.resize(size);
        for (unsigned ii = 0; ii < size; ii++) {
            if (counter1 > columns) {
                counter1 = 0; //column number
                counter2++; //row number
            }
            children.at(ii).x = counter1*(element_w + x_padding) + x;
            children.at(ii).y = counter2*(element_h + y_padding) + y;
            children.at(ii).width = element_w;
            children.at(ii).height = element_h;
        }
    }        
    void draw_children(std::vector<unsigned char>& cmd_str){
        for (unsigned ii=0; ii < children.size(); ii++) children.at(ii).draw(cmd_str);
    }
    void redraw_children(std::vector<unsigned char>& cmd_str) {
        for (unsigned ii=0; ii < children.size(); ii++) {
            children.at(ii).erase(cmd_str);
            children.at(ii).draw(cmd_str);
        }
    }
    void erase_children(std::vector<unsigned char>& cmd_str) {
        for (unsigned ii=0; ii < children.size(); ii++) children.at(ii).erase(cmd_str);
    }
    int reform(int num_elements, int cols, int x_in, int y_in) {
        unsigned int counter1=0, counter2=0;

        children.clear();
        children.resize(num_elements);
        columns = cols;
        x = x_in;
        y = y_in;
        for (unsigned ii = 0; ii < children.size(); ii++) {
            if (counter1 > columns) {
                counter1 = 0; //column number
                counter2++; //row number
            }
            children.at(ii).x = counter1*(element_w + x_padding) + x;
            children.at(ii).y = counter2*(element_h + y_padding) + y;
            children.at(ii).width = element_w;
            children.at(ii).height = element_h;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    int assign_text(std::vector<string> text) {
        for (unsigned ii=0; ii<children.size() || ii < text.size(); ii++) {
            //This is only valid if my type is a Button or Label but I want
            //the rest of the code for WidgetArray to be valid for any derived
            //class of Widget
            children.at(ii).text = text.at(ii);
        }
    }
};
```

I hope my question is clear. I've looked around and there's a *lot* of posts about template specialization, but I didn't find one that seemed to answer my question.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would specialize the cases you're describing in the first place. The widgets added must conform to whatever/however WidgetArray treats them, to be sure. Anything beyond that can be extended in derivations, i.e. `class ProgressBarArray : public WidgetArray<ProgressBar>`, and add the methods for progress-bars to *that* class; not a specialization? Or did I completely misread the question and the end-goal? In other words I'm not sure why you think specialization is the right answer here?

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. That would work. I guess I just got it in my head that since I was using templates, that must be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is simply a templated base class that contains all methods that are specific to both, which you then inherit from. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct base
{
protected:
    std::vector<T> children;
    ~base() { }

public:
    void draw_children();
    //Other methods common to all template parameters T

};


class WidgetArrayString
    : public base<std::string>
{
    //Methods specific only to strings
};

class WidgetArrayProgressBar
    : public base<ProgressBar>
{
    //Methods specific only to progress bar
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could inherit a specific template type like that.

Comment: @Beezum If thats the case, then the [CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) really ought to bake your noodle.